# config subdomain url

Tags: tomcat, config

I have a website with some links like the examples below:

```
http://mydomain/business/sellbook.action
http://mydomain/business/buybook.action
http://mydomain/merchant/managebook.action
```

Now I want to configure a subdomain for my application to directly link like below:

```
http://sell.mydomain/business/
http://buy.mydomain/business/
http://merchant.mydomain/
```

My application is built under this environment:

- Linux server
- Tomcat 6
- Java - Struts 2

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an Apache frontend using [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and the [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) Module to connect to the tomcats.